# How do I deselect a tool in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I've finished rotating and am trying to deselect the Rotate Tool. If I click on the image, the Rotate box reappears, undesiredly. If I click anywhere else, nothing happens.

The Select > None tool is unavailable and greyed.

[image]

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I wrote overhead: "If I click on the image, the Rotate box reappears, undesiredly. "

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Ah sorry. I'd like to move that eye with the eyedropper under the eye.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Quandary solved. Thanks!

Comment: @dsstorefile1 BTW, please feel free to consolidate your comments into an answer, to allow me to upload you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always an active tool in Gimp. To deselect a tool you have to select another one. Some people use the "Measure" tool as their default tool, since it is the one less likely to change something by mistake in the image.